# converting dot syntax to bracket syntax on a struct

Tags: objective-c

I have a property of CGSize:

```
@property (nonatomic) CGSize descriptionSize;
```

'

```
@synthesize descriptionSize = _descriptionSize;
```

I can access the height through the dot syntax:

```
self.descriptionSize.height = 35;
```

but how does this work with the bracket syntax?

```
[self setDescriptionSize:???];
```

Looked stupid simple to me, but I can't get the clue. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would try `[[self descriptionSize] setHeight:35]`

Comment: @mttrb ...can ***not*** send a `setHeight` message to it.

Comment: You could say `self.descriptionSize = CGSizeMake(self.descriptionSize.width, 35)`.

Comment: @fzwo Whoops, typo and it is too late to edit :(  What I meant to say is "@user1212112 CGSize is a struct not an object so you can NOT send a setHeight message to it."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is one of the pitfalls of dot notation for properties: Those two dots in self.descriptionSize.height look the same but mean very different things. The first is a property accessor which maps to a "get descriptionSize" method, but the second is an old-school struct reference. The first dot returns a CGSize ***scalar***, NOT a pointer to the size value in the object. When the second dot sets the height in that returned CGSize, it's setting a value on the stack instead of changing the value in the object. This is how you have to do it:

```
CGSize size = self.descriptionSize;
size.height = 35;
self.descriptionSize = size;
```

…or the equivalent without <strike>properties</strike> dot notation:

```
CGSize size = [self descriptionSize];
size.height = 35; // we still use the dot here: size is a struct not an object
[self setDescriptionSize:size];
```

Comment: +1, however, you mean "equivalent without dot notation"--property vs. manual accessors and square bracket vs. dot notation are two completely independent choices.

Comment: Also, if you want to one-line it, there's `[self setDescriptionSize:CGMakeSize([self descriptionSize].width,35)];`

Comment: I'm pretty sure the only difference between the two is syntax—as I understand it, they should compile to exactly the same code.

Comment: What I'm saying is you've confused the concept of properties and the concept of dot notation--they're two different things. You may use square brackets with properties, and you may use dot syntax with manually-defined accessors. It's important to know that your second example works just fine with properties, and your first works just fine without them.

Comment: Exactly what @andyvn22 said;  the dot notation and properties are entirely orthogonal.   You can use the one without ever using the other.    Answer fixed.

Answer (score 5):

The implementation of `descriptionSize` will return a *copy* of the `CGSize` struct, so you can't work directly with that and hope it will work.  What you need to do is get the whole of the `CGSize` struct, modify it, and then pass it back in:

```
CGSize size = [self descriptionSize];
size.height = 35;
[self setDescriptionSize:size];
```

However given you are working on a property of `self` and the property isn't an *object*, which requires memory management, the most efficient way of modifying the size is:

```
_descriptionSize.height = 35;
```

However you'd use the former getter/setter approach if:

1. The object was not `self`.
2. You had manually written the setter method to do something as a side-effect of changing the size (for example invalidating bits of the view in order to automatically update the view).

Answer (score 2):

Dot syntax can mean two different things: Either a struct reference (CGSize is a C struct), or an objective-C message send.

Theoretically, if you have a method like `- (void)doSomething;`, you could call it like this: `myObject.doSomething; //bad style`. Don't do this. Dot syntax is not meant for calling methods that actually do stuff, other than getting or setting values (although nothing in the language or the IDE is going to stop you).

Synthesizing properties creates accessor methods: `- (myType)myProperty` and `- (void)setMyProperty:(myType)newValue`. Here, dot syntax lets you access the getter in the ordinary way (because the getter is an ordinary Objective-C method), and has a special case for the setter: `myObject.myProperty = newValue` gets translated to `[myObject setMyProperty:newValue]`.

This means you can switch between dot syntax and Objective-C style message sending syntax for properties (and technically for all other parameter-less Objective-C method sends), but you *must* use dot syntax to access struct members. Structs are not objects, and they know now methods.