# Understanding objective-c dot notation

Tags: objective-c

I am learning objective-c, and as part of my learning I am trying to convert dot notation where I see it, back to bracket notation (I prefer bracket notation for now)

So my current view of the world is:

1. Objective-c prior to 2.0 had dot notation for structs only?
2. Objective-c 2.0 introduced dot notation for properties.  This allows accessing setters / getters via dot notation?
3. Messages cannot be sent to structs?

In a book I'm reading, I came accross the below code, and on my first few attempts, I failed miserably to convert it to bracket notation.

```
...
CGRect switchViewFrame = switchView.frame;
switchViewFrame.origin.y += [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size.height;
```

Having dug a bit deeper, I came to the following conclusions...

1. switchViewFrame.origin.y cannot be converted to bracket notation because switchViewFrame is defined as a CGRect, which is a struct in apples documentation, therefore the dot notation is necessary?
2. The rvalue on the second line is a combination of brackets and dots because shareApplication is a class method of UIApplication, and therefore a message is sent, but statusBarFrame is defined as a property of CGRect i.e. a struct and therefore dot notation is required?

Any help to clarify these points would be much appreciated.

If I have completely misunderstood and you can in fact convert it to bracket notation, could you please explain why.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Objective-c prior to 2.0 had dot notation for structs only? **Yes, as far as I know.**
2) Objective-c 2.0 introduced dot notation for properties. This allows accessing setters / getters via dot notation? **Yes.**
3) Messages cannot be sent to structs? **Correct, sending a message is equivalent to calling a method in the object the message is sent to.**
4) `switchViewFrame.origin.y` cannot be converted to bracket notation because `switchViewFrame` is defined as a `CGRect`, which is a `struct` in apples documentation, therefore the dot notation is necessary? **Yes.**
5) The `rvalue` on the second line is a combination of brackets and dots because `shareApplication` is a class method of `UIApplication`, and therefore a message is sent, but `statusBarFrame` is defined as a property of `CGRect` i.e. a `struct` and therefore dot notation is required? **No: `statusBarFrame` is a property of an `UIApplication` object. But `statusBarFrame` is a `struct` with components `origin` and `size`, which are also `structs`.**
So you were nearly everywhere right.

Comment: To clarify #5. The code could be written as `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarFrame].size.height;`. Accessing the property's value is the same (actually it is translated to) a call to the corresponding "getter" method.

Comment: To clarify #1;  that isn't "dot notation for structs".  That is simply a structure access in a fashion that C has always had.  The two are completely orthogonal (which is why we standardized on *not using dot notation anywhere*).

Comment: @bbum: an aside -- who's 'we'? A unit at Apple? I get a sense that dot notation is going out of favour there (based on NDA-covered stuff).

Comment: @Cris  "We" in this case is the Apple TV team.

Comment: @bbum: interesting that such an upper-echelon team of obj-c users chooses that as a standard.

Comment: @bbum Hi bbum, could you explain what you mean by "not using dot notation anywhere"? Does this mean all of he code you write doesn't use any dot notation? I'm just learning objective-c and I'd rather not use dot notation if I can help it.

Comment: @mickeysox Sure -- We don't use the dot syntax anywhere that it would cause a method call.   Instead, we use `[foo setBar:baz]` or `[foo bar]`.   Even for things declared as `@property`.

Comment: Thanks @bbum - I'm guessing that you still need dot notation to access structs? Sorry I'm just trying to understand where I absolutely need to use dot notation and where I don't, and it seems I only need to ever use it to access C structs e.g. CGRect.  I tend to think books shouldn't use dot notation because it hides what it's actually doing - but for gurus like yourself, do as you please :-)

Comment: @mickeysox A struct access is not a method call.  Thus, yes, we use the dot for traditional straight C purposes all the time.   I tend to agree with your assessment of books.  In general, there seems to be a lot of collusion of the dot with properties when the two are entirely orthogonal.

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10444012/2449268

Explains it really well, hope it answers your question.

Also you may use bracket notation on frame as below:

CGRect switchViewFrame = switchView.frame;
switchViewFrame.origin.y += [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarFrame].size.height;