# What is the -(CGRect *)frame method in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller, properties

1. Codes:

   ```
   if (!CGRectContainsPoint([[viewArray objectAtIndex:0]  frame], CGPointMake(newX, newY)) )
   {
        ....
   }
   ```
2. Question

I wanna to get a "frame" value of a UIView  in a view array, so i used this:

```
 ((UIView *)[viewArray objectAtIndex:0]).frame
```

I utilize (UIView *) to compulsively convert an id object  to UIView, otherwise it will trigger error like "Property 'frame' not found on object of type 'id'". But the method below seems successfully escape from this error:

```
  [[viewArray objectAtIndex:0] frame]
```

So [id frame] can Automatically detect the id's real type and then make it to call the method? 
I really wanna to know methods like 
[id frame]----id's real type is UIView
[id view ]----id's real type is UIViewController

Are these methods getter methods or setter methods? I cannot tell the diffrence and the apple document show them like :

```
 @property(nonatomic) CGRect frame
```

Thx a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The method called in the end is `-(CGRect)frame;`. Using the dot syntax is just a syntactic sugar the objective-c compiler provides. For this sugar to work, the compiler needs to know the type of the object it uses.

On the other end, objective-c uses message passing for calling methods. Which means that when you use the syntax `[id message]`, it will try to execute the selector `@selector(message)` on `id`. `id` being a special type denoting any object in the runtime, it accepts every selector and will throw an unknown selector exception at runtime if the object cannot execute it.

Comment: Readers, please correct me if I'm wrong. This is my understanding of how objective-c works, but I dont want to give OP false information.

Comment: When you say "For this sugar to work...", I suspect you're correct but it would be interesting to know why it needs to do more than convert the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

By defining a property like: `@property(nonatomic) CGRect frame` the property works as both a getter and setter.

For example, to modify the width of a frame, you might write:

```
CGRect frame = myView.frame;
frame.size.width = 100;
myView.frame = frame;
```

For a good description of dot notation, see this fine [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10443771/converting-dot-syntax-to-bracket-syntax-on-a-struct/10444012#10444012).